# How to configure git username and password permanently in Visual Studio Code in Linux?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, linux-mint

I am using Visual Studio Code in Linux mint. I am being asked for git username and password, every time I try to push using GIT SOURCE CONTROL given in Visual Studio Code. How to configure git username and password in Vscode permanently?

Picture example can be found in this link.
[Username & password promt picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQ87m.png)

Comment: A proper way is to configure [ssh keys](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) instead of passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Is not a vscode issue. Is your machine issue. So, instead of type username and password every single time, you can generate a ssh key and push the public part into your remote. Witch service are you using? Github? Bitbucket? Another one? 
 ... generate your own ssh key:

```
ssh-keygen
```

And then add the key on the machine where you will push your code. Look for the right way to add the public key in the destination's website.